# php login verification returns 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, mysql, azure, mysqli

I am trying to learn PHP and have an issue in verifying a login attempt with my mysql database. Whenever I try to run the script I get a 500 (Internal Server Error).

The server is configured correctly and every other file is working fine. I have also tried increasing the PHP memory limit, but no luck. So Google tells me it must be an error in my PHP, but I do not see it. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

My login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form action="loginverification.php" method="post">
    <table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Username:</td>
       <td><input name="username" type="text"></td>
       <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Password:</td>
       <td><input name="password" type="text"></td>
       <td></td>
      </tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td><input type="submit"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my loginverification.php:

```
<?php

$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = '';
$port = '';

$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $port);


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 printf('Could not connect: %s\n', $mysqli_connect_error);
 exit();
} else {
 echo "Success";
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$results = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE username=? AND password=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($results);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $username,$password);
$stmt->execute();

if($results->fetch() == false) {
 error_log("User $username: password doesn't match.");
 echo '{"success":0,"error_message":"Invalid Username/Password"}';
} else {
 echo '{"success":1}';
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

I am working on Azure, with PHP 5.4.

Comment: Also add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP scripts and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: the official support for 5.4 ended on 3 September 2015, please upgrade and stop using obsolete software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call the `fetch()` method on `$results` which in your code is a string. You have to use the statement (`$stmt`).

Have fun learning!